# MUI Typescript Custom Component | How does one achieve a dynamic type based on the 'component' prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Issue 1: As stated in the title, how does one achieve a prop, say a prop named `dynamicallyTypedProp`, to be typed differently based on what the `component` prop is passed as, using [@mui/material](https://mui.com/) to create the custom component? I've tried looking at how the MUI core team has implemented their TS in both `@mui/material` and `@mui/joy` without success. For example https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/c80ff0339882859af7e17f8bfd0a5f6880b323f8/packages/mui-material/src/Button/Button.d.ts#L98-L109.

Issue 2: Another thing I'm not sure is **where** and how to correctly type the `component` prop as `@mui/joy` types it using it's internal `useThemeProps` ([found here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/c80ff0339882859af7e17f8bfd0a5f6880b323f8/packages/mui-joy/src/Button/Button.tsx#L159)), which I can't use as I'm using `@mui/material` and **not** `@mui/joy`.

I've created a [Codesandbox playground here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-component-dynamically-typed-dym6ob?file=/src/components/Media/MediaProps.ts).

```js
// src/App.tsx

import './styles.css'
import Media from './components/Media'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Media
        component="picture"
        // Part of issue 1
        // Expect NO TS error
        dynamicallyTypedProp={[]}
      />
      <Media
        component="picture"
        // Part of issue 1
        // Expect TS error
        dynamicallyTypedProp={{}}
      />
      <Media
        component="img"
        // Part of issue 1
        // Expect NO TS error
        dynamicallyTypedProp={{}}
      />
      <Media
        component="img"
        // Part of issue 1
        // Expect TS error
        dynamicallyTypedProp={[]}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
// src/components/Media/MediaProps.ts

import * as React from 'react'
import {
  OverridableComponent,
  OverrideProps,
  OverridableTypeMap,
} from '@mui/types'

export type Default = Record<string, any>
export type Picture = Array<any>

export interface MediaTypeMap<P = {}, D extends React.ElementType = 'img'> {
  props: P & {
    children?: React.ReactNode
    src?: string
  }
  defaultComponent: D
}

export type MediaProps<
  D extends React.ElementType = MediaTypeMap['defaultComponent'],
  P = { component?: React.ElementType }
> = OverrideProps<MediaTypeMap<P, D>, D>

// Part of issue 1
// Currently experimenting with code below to get dynamic type to work with no success.

export interface ExtendMediaTypeMap<M extends OverridableTypeMap> {
  props: M['props'] &
    (M['props'] extends { component?: 'picture' }
      ? MediaTypeMap['props'] & { dynamicallyTypedProp: Picture }
      : MediaTypeMap['props'] & { dynamicallyTypedProp: Default })
  defaultComponent: M['defaultComponent']
}

export type ExtendMedia<M extends OverridableTypeMap> = ((
  props: { component: 'picture' } & OverrideProps<
    ExtendMediaTypeMap<M>,
    'picture'
  >,
) => JSX.Element) &
  OverridableComponent<ExtendMediaTypeMap<M>>
```

```js
// src/components/Media/MediaProps.tsx

import * as React from 'react'
import { styled, useThemeProps } from '@mui/material'
import { ExtendMedia, MediaProps, MediaTypeMap } from './MediaProps'

const MediaRoot = styled('img', {
  name: 'MyMedia',
  slot: 'Root',
  overridesResolver: (props, styles) => styles.root,
})<{ ownerState: MediaProps }>({
  display: 'flex',
})

const Media = React.forwardRef(function Media(inProps, ref) {
  const props = useThemeProps({ props: inProps, name: 'MyMedia' })
  const {
    // Part of issue 2
    // Expect NO TS error from `component`.
    component = 'img',
    dynamicallyTypedProp,
    ...other
  } = props

  // Part of issue 1
  if (component === 'picture') {
    console.log(dynamicallyTypedProp) // Expect Picture type, getting Default.
  } else {
    console.log(dynamicallyTypedProp) // Expect Default type, getting Default.
  }

  const ownerState = {
    ...props,
    component,
  }

  return <MediaRoot ownerState={ownerState} ref={ref} {...other} />
}) as ExtendMedia<MediaTypeMap>

export default Media
```

I'm relatively new to Typescript and so I'm not entirely sure how to go about this and what to expect of Typescript. Is this perhaps not possible? Ideally the solution would be in a [MUI-esque style](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/c80ff0339882859af7e17f8bfd0a5f6880b323f8/packages/mui-material/src/Button/Button.d.ts) implementing a `MediaTypeMap` interface & a `MediaProps` type as they do in the MUI core package.

Any help is appreciated!